# How to change a Checkbox attribute on click of parent <tr>

Tags: jquery

I need small suggestion from you.

Onclick of       the checkbox attribute inside that  should be changed.There is also a  inside  the

HTML Code:

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td class="answer"><input tabindex="4" type="checkbox" name="Dum1_4" id="Dum1_4" value="1"/></td>
 <td class="answerlabel"><label for="Dum1_4" id="Dum1_4_label"><table class="sample"><tr><td><img src="/ThumbsV2/2200000999-f.png"></td></tr><tr><td><b>Product 4</b></td></tr><tr><td>Product Description 4</td></tr><tr><td><b>Price 4</b></td></tr></table></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="answer"><input tabindex="5" type="checkbox" name="Dum1_5" id="Dum1_5" value="1"/></td>
<td class="answerlabel"><label for="Dum1_5" id="Dum1_5_label"><table class="sample"><tr><td><img src="/ThumbsV2/2200001080-f.png"></td></tr><tr><td><b>Product 5</b></td></tr><tr><td>Product Description 5</td></tr><tr><td><b>Price 5</b></td></tr></table></label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is my code:

```
$('.sample').click(function()
{       
row =$this.parents("td");
row.siblings().find("input:checkbox").attr("checked","checked" );
}
});
});
```

Please someone help me!

Comment: From jQuery 1.6 use "prop()" for boolean attributes. See [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for more information.
`$(this).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: I have tried below code                               $(document).ready(function()
        {
     $('TABLE TBODY TR TD TABLE').click(function()
                                                   {
                                                        $(this).parents('td').prev('td').find('input:checkbox').attr("checked",false );

                                                   }
                  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('TABLE > TBODY > TR').click(function()
{
    $('input:checkbox', $(this)).prop("checked", "checked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('TABLE TBODY TR').click(function()
{
    $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

There's a decent [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript) about manipulating checkboxes with jQuery

[View example here](http://jsfiddle.net/88TPk/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to toggle the selected state, use the following:

**jQuery 1.6+**

```
$('table tbody tr').click(function() {
    $('input:checkbox', this).prop('checked', function(index, oldValue) {
        return !oldValue;
    });
});
```

**jQuery pre-1.6**

```
$('table tbody tr').toggle(function() {
    $('input:checkbox', this).attr('checked', 'checked');
}, function() {
    $('input:checkbox', this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of the attribute to `"checked"` should work.

```
$('TABLE TBODY TR').click(function()
{
    $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/eHAt3/).

Comment: Hello Jon,thanks for your response..But sorry to say that still it is not working :-(

Comment: Could we see some of the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked","checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery 1.6, the code is more readable:

```
$("table tbody tr").click(function(){
    $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this was working fine for me:

```
$('#checkall').click(function() {
$('#cause').children().each(function() {    
                        $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", $('#checkall').prop("checked"));
                    });
                });
```

just use it without the each function / check / uncheck all elements