# How to toggle content of <td>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would very much like to be able to [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) having an x and not having an x in

```
<td class="checkbox"> <input name="signed" type="checkbox" checked /> x </td>
```

See JSFiddle for example

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/GMSCW/

The code that is triggered when Submit is pressed is

```
$('form').live('submit', function(){
   $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
         // do something here on success
   },'json');
   return false;
});
```

I assume I have to something in the lines of

```
$(this).getElementByClass("checkbox").td.toggle('x');
```

But `checked` should still be updated in the `<input name="signed" type="checkbox" checked />`

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Just to be clear, the jQuery Toggle command toggles the visibility. Not the checked status of a checkbox.

Comment: Do you want to toggle the checkbox _and_ the X at that same time?

Comment: So when "save" is pressed you want the x to go if the checkbox is not checked?

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307120/how-to-change-a-checkbox-attribute-on-click-of-parent-tr/6307165#6307165 which was asked about 20 minutes ago.

Comment: @Jay : Yes, just that =)

Comment: @dotty : Yes, exactly =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w5nAr/3/) it's based off the work by Bryan.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the X in a span and then hide that

```
<td class="checkbox"> 
      <input name="signed" type="checkbox" checked />
      <span id='toggleme'>x</span>
 </td>

 //change the visibility of the x
 $('#toggleme').toggle();

// check the checkbox
$('input[name=signed]').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

To check a checkbox in jQuery use you `ELEMENT.attr("checked","checked")` or the jQuery 1.6 way with `ELEMENT.prop("checked", true)`

Answer (score 1):

The best idea, IMO, is to put a `<label>` right next to the checkbox and then `toggle` it with `$("input[type=checkbox] + label", this).toggle()`.

To change the checkbox, the examples other users gave work just fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/w5nAr/

This assumes you don't want to change the checkbox, just the text next to it. If you want both, here's another example:

http://jsfiddle.net/w5nAr/4/

Comment: Very cool. Can the checkbox also toggle? Ie. when X is displayed, the checkbox should be checked. Can that be done?

Comment: Yeah, the other people gave good answers on that, so I won't duplicate their work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$({some identifier for your checkbox}).attr("checked",true)
```

Comment: Not everyone is on 1.6, so `attr()` is a better solution at the moment. But in the future we should defiantly use `prop()`

Comment: Here are some great answers on [how `prop()` and `attr()` differ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).